# How to get the header values of an SQL output into CSV from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I have to get values from a SQL procedure (where the no of columns vary with data - Using PIVOT ) into csv file. So when I write code to save a file to csv from C#, I cannot hardcode the header values. Is there a way that I can get to export the header values aswell?
     C# Code:

```
 public string GetCSVData ()
{
    try
    {
        Sql v = new Sql("Weekly_CSV");
        v.Run();
        DataTable dt=new DataTable(); 
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("1", typeof(String)); // here the number could be anything based on sql query
        dt.Columns.Add("10", typeof(String)); // here the number could be anything based on sql query

        dt.Columns.Add("21", typeof(String)); // here the number could be anything based on sql query

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in v.Results.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.GetString("Name"), item.GetString("Season"),item.GetString("weekdays"),item.GetString("weekNum"));

        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();

        string csvData = DataTableToCSVFile(dt);

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();

        string filename = "Weekly.csv";
        response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\";");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", csvData.Length.ToString());
        response.Write(csvData);
        response.Flush();           
        response.End();         

}
    private string DataTableToCSVFile(DataTable dt)
 {
    DataTable dtExcel = dt;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Weekly - CSV");
    sb.Append("\n");

    foreach (DataColumn column in dtExcel.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append(column.ColumnName + ",");

    }
    sb.Append("\n");
    foreach (DataRow row in dtExcel.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(row[i].ToString() + ",");
        }
        sb.Append("\n");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Part of my Procedure: (Giving only bits from the procedure)

```
  /* COLUMNS HEADERS */
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @columnHeaders = COALESCE (@columnHeaders 
+ ',[' + CAST(weekNum as varchar(4)) + ']', '[' + CAST(weekNum as varchar(4)) + ']')
FROM    (select distinct(weekNum) from (
                Select Season, ------------ \\ Rest of the query... the result is fetching 3 rows.
 /* Actual query that used the @columnHeaders values */
set @query = N'SELECT Name,' + @columnHeaders + N' from 
             (
                Select ----------------- \\rest of the query.
```

Now from the above procedure I get vales of headers from “@columnHeaders” which I cannot hardcode in C# fucntion “GetCSVData”.
How can I display the headers too in the csv output?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Aren't you already reading the column names in your DataTableToCSVFile method?

Comment: Not exactly. In my C# function, I have hardcoded them. ( 1,10 and 21). They happen to be the output values of the "columnHeaders " . So if the output is say "2,15,21" , the I need the new numbers to be header columns along with the name. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: What exactly is that Sql class? Is it a custom wrapper? You should be able to get the headers from a SqlDataReader. Just search around.